# How can I make this image stay fixed while fading away on scroll?

Tags: jquery, parallax

I have a site here...

http://matiny.tk/warframe/about/index.html

When you scroll near the bottom, you see a .png lotus image layered on top of an image with characters on it. Then you keep scrolling and the lotus picture scrolls away. What I want is for the lotus image to become locked in place when it's top reaches the top of the window (when it's in perfect full view). At that point, scrolling should make it fade, not move.

I was thinking I might make it position:fixed then use jQ to make it invisible until it reaches the right point, then make it fade on scroll.

The relevant text is mega simple...

```
<div class="char-div">
   <img src="http://matiny.tk/warframe/about/lotus.png" alt="" class="lotus"/>
</div>


.char-div {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(http://matiny.tk/warframe/about/chars.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 1500px;
}

.lotus {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zv59nq87/)**

```
var lotusFirstPosition=$('.lotus').offset().top;
var currentPosition;
var fadingDuration=400; // the duration it will take to fade the element
var OPI=1/fadingDuration; // Opacity Per Inch
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($('.lotus').offset().top<=$(document).scrollTop()){
        currentPosition=$(document).scrollTop();
        $('.lotus').css('top',$(document).scrollTop()+'px');
    }
    else if(currentPosition>=lotusFirstPosition){
        currentPosition=$(document).scrollTop();
        $('.lotus').css('top',$(document).scrollTop()+'px');
    }
    else{
        $('.lotus').css('top',lotusFirstPosition+'px');
    }
    $('.lotus').css('opacity',1-((currentPosition-lotusFirstPosition)*OPI));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to ask, is the last line of code based on percentage scrolled?

Comment: nope it is based on the pixels scrolled after the image is stuck at the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should also post your javascript for completeness of your question here in SO.

To answer your question, yes, you can change the position of your image to fixed when the image tip hits the top. Then as you scroll, you can change the opacity until it becomes completely invisible.